# I am wondering if my query would work because it is different from the solutions and it is just a theoretical task without a Database

Tags: sqlite, subquery, except, not-exists

I've got the following task: Find each company hat is located in every city in which 'FBC' is located.
Follwoing entities:

```
employee(ID, person_name, street, city)
works(ID, company_name, salary)
company(company_name, city)
manages(ID, manager_id)
```

I wrote the following query:

```
select company_name
from company
where city in
(select city
from company
where company_name = 'FBC')
```

They used a nested query with not exists and exept but I found that too complicated.
What do you mean?
Thanks and best regards!

Comment: What if a company is located in every city in which 'FBC' is located but also in other cities too?

Comment: I understood the question that I have to find each company that is sharing a location.

Comment: So in the results there will be all companies even if they share only 1 common city with FBC?

Comment: Yes, exactly. One common city suffices.

Comment: Then your query is almost correct. Change to `select distinct company_name...` so you get each company only once and in the where clause add `and company_name<>'FBC'` so FBC is not in the results.

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot!